# Incorrect Answers when evaluating a String

Tags: java, javascript, scriptengine

My code looks like this:

```
    ScriptEngineManager factory = new ScriptEngineManager();
    ScriptEngine engine = factory.getEngineByName("JavaScript");
    int x = 10;
    engine.eval("x =" + x);
    System.out.println((Boolean) engine.eval("x < 5"));
    System.out.println((Boolean) engine.eval("2 < x < 5"));
```

The first SOP prints false as expected, but the second SOP prints true. It doesn't give correct results when I compare the variable with two values. It gives true, even if half of the condition is true. Any workaround for this? Please suggest. Thanks.

Comment: `2 < x < 5` doesn't do what you think it does...

Comment: I suggest using syntax that more accurately reflects what you're trying to do ;)

Comment: `2 < x < 5 => (2 < 10 ) < 5 => (true) < 5 => 1 < 5 => true`!!

Comment: It's essentially (2 < 10) < 5, which evaluates to true < 5 which evaluates to true, because true is 1.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`2 < x < 5` doesn't do what you think it does.  It's evaluated as follows:

```
2 < x < 5
(2 < x) < 5
(2 < 10) < 5
true < 5
1 < 5
true
```

Try `(2 < x) && (x < 5)` instead.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Appreciate that.

Answer (score 4):

Turning my comment to an anwser

`2 < x < 5 => (2 < 10 ) < 5 => (true) < 5 => 1 < 5 => true`

Answer (score 3):

No it is actually producing the correct result. Your expression is evaluated like this:

1. 2 < x => true
2. true < 5 => 1 < 5 (type coercion)
3. 1 < 5 => true
4. true

Answer (score 1):

To work around try specifying that both conditions must be met.

System.out.println((Boolean) engine.eval("2 < x && x < 5"));